# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation gets called but app interface does not reorients (only the status bar reorients)

Tags: ios, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, interface-orientation

I am trying to build an app that only works for landscape device orientations on iOS devices. That means my shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation returns true for only landscape device orientations. However at some points of time, I need to switch to portrait device orientation for which I use setStatusBarOrientation API.

After holding the device in any landscape orientation and setting the interface orientation to default/upside down by using **setStausBarOrientation** API, and just tilting the device slightly in the held orientation orientation only, the status bar rotates but the interface does not rotates. shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation does get called and returns true but still interface does not reorient. Also, problem gets solved if I rotate the device in opposite orientation. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using multiple view controllers? If your shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation methods do not match each other you can get this sort of behavior. You might set them all to YES for everything, and decide what to do when it rotates. Keep in mind that your user is rotating the device, probably for a reason. You can push a new VC or whatever you want upon rotation, so consider all the options. Good luck.

Comment: I get this problem only when setStausBarOrientation has been called once to rotate the view to a particular orientation and then I tilt the device to the orientation in which it was held and now I expect the view to reorient automatically. The status bar does reorient but the view does not.

Comment: If it were me, I would debug from didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: and see what's going on. As an aside, in all my development (not that much, admittedly) I've never had occasion to use setStatusBarOrientation. Good luck! This rotation stuff certainly ate a few days of my time before I grokked it.

Comment: The sad part is that didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation never gets called in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple have accepted this as a bug in their SDK and they might fix the issue in the next release.